# Qt - Creating a notification at a certain time (PC)

Tags: c++, qt

For school I have to create a calendar program for the PC with Qt,
this calendar also has to give notifications a certain time before some scheduled appointment starts.

But i have trouble finding out how I exactly can create this notifications without using a while loop (which will stop my program), I would be really thankfully if someone can help me a bit with that certain part of my project.

Thank you,
Dennis

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a `QTimer` instance with interval set to 1 second. Then connect to `QTimer::timeout()` signal and in the slot you can check whether there is any appointment approaching, something like that:

```
void YourClass::slotNameForTimeoutSignal()
{
    static const int fifteenMinutes = 15 * 60;
    foreach (const Appointment& app : allAppoitments)
    {
        if ((app.getStartUnixTime() - QDateTime::currentDateTime().toTime_t()) <= fifteenMinutes)
        {
            notifyAboutTheAppointment(app); // implement this method to display notification
        }
    }
}
```

This code assumes you have some kind of `Appointment` class/structure which holds unixtime when the appoitment starts. The timer setup is easy. Somewhere in your application initialization create a timer (which should be a member field in your class), set it up and run:

```
YourClass::YourClass()
{
    timer = new QTimer(this);
    connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(slotNameForTimeoutSignal()));
    timer->setInterval(1000);
    timer->setSingheShot(false);
    timer->start();
}
```

If you didn't know it yet, the unixtime is a time format, which is a integer number - a number of seconds that passed since the begining of 1970. Here's more details: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time

Also if you're not familar with signals/slots in Qt, you should really read first about those in Qt documentation.

Comment: Oh i didn't knew there was a QTimer, I think i could let it work with this, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can subclass [QCalendarWidget](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qcalendarwidget.html) to create your GUI i.e. the user can select the date when he wants the appointment. Use the [QTimer](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtimer.html) to trigger the SIGNAL at your precise appointment time.

Now you can get the current date and time using [QDateTime](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qdatetime.html).

```
1. Check if the appointment is on the same date as current.
2. If yes jump to step no 4.
3. Set a timer using QTimer to emit a SIGNAL after 24 hours and connect this SIGNAL to your custom SLOT which will check if the current date is same as appointment date. Continue this step until your current date is same as appointment date.
4. Calculate the time difference between  your appointment and current time and set this difference to a QTimer which will emit a SIGNAL at the required time.
5. This emitted SIGNAL would be connected a SLOT in which you are doing whatever is needed when the appointment is reached
```

I hope this helps you get in track.
Giving code would be like solving your homework which I don't want to do.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you exactly mean to be honest. (I'm only in my first year of Computer Science)

Comment: @Dennis what is the problem that you are facing? I am assuming that you are familiar with basic C++ and Qt concepts like signals and slots... If not please make it clear

Comment: Yes, but that's something I already have actually. The Datetime when the notification has to be shown is saved, but how can I use this datetime to show the notification? Because I'm not sure how to send a signal at a certain time without using the said while-loop which will stop my program from working till the said datetime has passed

Comment: Can you please show the simplified code of what you have done so far?

Comment: Well my DateTime is saved in `QDateTime m_notify`, now the problem is i can't use something like `if(m_notify > QDateTime::currentDateTime() ) notifyAppointment();` because it has to be putted into a while loop